# PPA for bleeding edge version of Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10

I have been reading about some great new features in Ubuntu 12.10's Unity, like photo lens and right click actions and so on, but I don't want to upgrade due to missing features and bugs in the current (very early) build of 12.10.

So can I just get the Unity version used in 12.10 ?

Comment: You should assume that the bleeding edge version of Unity, which as you know is an integral part of Ubuntu 12.10, has a high risk of the same "missing features and bugs".

Comment: I know but I just wanted to try it without a full upgrade and then I could just revert Unity if its to buggy for every day use

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to try out the new Unity, I would recommend you to download the latest [12.10 daily build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) and create a bootable medium out of it. Then you can boot from it and try out the new Unity without messing up your stable system.